# Degeneracy despite Interaction

Tags: particle-physics, condensed-matter, hilbert-space, interactions

Lifting of degeneracies of a composite system through interactions among its constituents is a generic theme of all physical systems - from splitting of $s-$orbital energies when two hydrogen atoms are brought nearby to the frequency splitting of propagating modes in optical waveguides. Through this post I am looking for an exception to this rule:

*Is there any entity in physics (say real particles, or may be abstract ones) where two identical copies of those entities when brought closer and closer to each other, and are allowed to interact, instead of showing a monotonically increasing energy gap with decreasing interaction length, they show sinusoidal variations and at times degenerate energy levels?*

Comment: over what length scale?  For small $x$ the function $\sin(x)$ is linear...

Comment: Interaction length scale can vary characteristic to the system. Say for the example of formation of hydrogen molecule, the length scale is on the order of Bohr radius, for the waveguide set up, it is on the order of wavelength of the propagating light.

So as you can see, I am actually asking for a system where the identical particles (hydrogen atom, propagating photons) are interacting but their energy levels are not splitting in a conventional way as in other prototypical systems.

Comment: I don’t think you understood my comment.  Unless *you* clarify over what length scale you want this change, I can take a series expansion and truncate keeping at most the linear term and *never* see anything but linear or constant splitting.

Comment: If $x$ is the distance between the two "particles" normalized to the characteristic interaction length scale $L$ (which is, of course, dependent upon the system, say Bohr radius, light wavelength, Schwarzschild radius etc) then I am thinking of $x \simeq 1$. This precludes the asymptotatic cases $x \ll 1$ (where new interaction of a different origin with a different length scale may take place) or $x \gg 1$ (where there is no interaction).

I hope it clarified your question.

Comment: Right.  *You* might care to clarify *your* question.